# 4k+ users quickly casting delete votes

Tags: discussion

I was surprised to see that [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/17146/5836) had both a down vote and a delete vote within an hour or so of it being posted. While I could be wrong, it seems likely a that 4k+ user read the answer, disliked it, down voted it and voted to delete it. I understand that 4k+ users have that privilege, but should we be using it that way? I understand that users can use their privileges however they like, but I would like to understand the consensus of the community.

Comment: Given that it would take 2 more votes to actually delete the answer, is this a real problem?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh it is unlikely a problem in terms of things getting deleted, but it does not seem friendly to me. I just wanted t to get a better understanding of the community's thoughts on the issue.

Comment: Most likely, it's a symptom of the broader phenomenon on here of over-eagerness to put on hold, close or delete things.

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumption is not helpful - we have no way to tell whether this was one user or two. An hour is not a rapid response when folks are up, so rather than try and second-guess voters, let's focus on what it means.

Nothing, basically - this would require others to also vote to delete.

That said, I agree it isn't delete-worthy. I have downvoted it as it was not a good answer, but it does at least appear to try and answer the question.